# Wordpress and CSS not working as I expect

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have CSS code that I want to run only on a certain page ID. Historically this has not been much of a problem, but I am nowhere near an expert with CSS. Below is the code for making a table mobile friendly and it works great!  BUT, it is running on all pages and not just the one page ID I have set it for.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    .page-id-17075   table, 
         thead, 
         tbody, 
         th, 
         td, 
         tr { display: block; }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    .page-id-17075   thead tr { 
            position: absolute;
            top: -9999px;
            left: -9999px;
        }

    .page-id-17075  tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    .page-id-17075   td { 
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 50%; 
            white-space: normal;
            text-align:left;
        }


    .page-id-17075  td:before { 
            /* Now like a table header */
            position: absolute;
            /* Top/left values mimic padding */
            top: 6px;
            left: 6px;
            width: 45%; 
            padding-right: 10px; 
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-align:left;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        /*
        Label the data
        */

    .page-id-17075 td.tg-031e { text-align: center; }
    .page-id-17075  td:nth-of-type(1) { background-color: #eee !important; }    

    .page-id-17075  th.tg-zlxb {display: none !important;}
    .page-id-17075  td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "company 1"; }
    .page-id-17075  td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "company 2"; }
    .page-id-17075  td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "company 3"; }
    .page-id-17075  td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "company 4"; }
```

}

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are all styles applied to the non-targeted pages, or is it only your first rule (the one that sets the table as `display:block`)?

Comment: Impossible to tell if you don't post your code including your HTML. We're not wizards who can predict what your website looks like based off css alone. Ideally include a functioning jsfiddle example with the `<>` button.  Refer to the [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please! :)

Comment: @Joseph Marikle It's only the first block actually; which I did not know until you asked.

Comment: I would suggest rather enqeue a seperate css stylesheet for the specific page rather than hard coding the classes. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61244/wp-enqueue-style-on-specific-page-templates refers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @josephmarikle for putting me on the correct path.  I need to specifically identify the table I needed to get it to work.

```
/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    .page-id-17075  #wpsm-table-1,  
         .wpsm-tbody tbody, 
         .wpsm-tbody th, 
         .wpsm-tbody td, 
         .wpsm-tbody tr { display: block; }
```